# I have my maiden name with my employer. but my passport has new legal name so should I apply B visa with maiden name or new legal name?

Tags: b1-b2-visas

My employer has my maiden name and now they are applying my B1 visa but my passport has my new legal name?

so should I apply B visa with maiden name or new legal name same as passport?

Comment: Which name would you rather be known by? Not an answer, but wouldn't it be simplest to notify your employer of your name change, or is there a reason you don't want to do that? (You can normally travel with a visa in a different name to your passport if you have documents proving a name change, but it's certainly easier if the visa has the same name as your passport; I'm not sure if there are any other factors involved, e.g. with the visa application, but people getting married and changing their names is hardly unusual, so it's unlikely to be a problem.)

Comment: Applying in your maiden name makes little sense. You’ll have to supply evidence of the name change anyway, so changing your employer’s record should make things much simpler.

Comment: Do you have a strong desire for preferring to be known professionally by your maiden name?

Comment: Do you mean that you have changed your legal name after starting to work with your employer? Then yes, you most probably should inform the employer about the name change, and this will resolve the issue.

Comment: The fact that you got married does not automatically mean your name has changed. You have to actually apply for a name change.

Comment: @DJClayworth different countries have different practices in this regard but in any event we can assume OP has gone through whatever practice is required in their country if they already have a passport in the new name

Comment: In some companies it is the practice for company employees to purchase airplane tickets on behalf of traveling employees. Be sure the name on the ticket matches the name on the passport.